# Querying the latest 30 records for a customer using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a scada application running on a mobile phone and need to display that last 30 alarms from a site per customer, when the alarm screen is opened for that site. I have tried using a View which seemed to work but now doesn't bring back new records. The query uses the TOP function. The SQL Server database is a virtual database running on MS Azure.

Below is the query from the 'grid' object in the SCADA app.

```
ALARMHISTORYVIEW WHERE al_tag LIKE '{SoPump_ptr.label}%' 
ORDER BY al_event_time DESC
```

The grid also allows me to limit the results to the last 30 records using the TOP (30) function

Here is the `ALARMHISTORYVIEW` in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    Al_Event_Time, Al_Message, Al_Tag, Al_Start_Time, 
    Al_Norm_Time, Al_Ack_Time, Al_Station
FROM            
    dbo.ALARMHISTORY
WHERE        
    (Al_Station LIKE '%Clearscada-A%')
GROUP BY 
    Al_Event_Time, Al_Message, Al_Tag, Al_Start_Time, 
    Al_Norm_Time, Al_Ack_Time, Al_Station
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
SELECT TOP 30 *
FROM [table_name]
ORDER BY [column_name] DESC
```